# Multi column table doesn't always align

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I would like the first table to end where the fourth column of the second table starts.
Sizes are `9+1+2.5+2.5` cm for the first table and `9+1+5+1` cm for the second one.
I get better (but not perfect) results using `9+1+2.25+2.25` cm, and the error persists even if I use `9+1+3+3` for the first table and `9+1+6+1` for the second one.
Why does this happen?

[image: Third and fourth column aren't aligned]

The document code is

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.3}

\section{Course list}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{9cm}|p{1cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{First Table}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Couse} & \textbf{ECTS} &\textbf{Period} & \textbf{Language} \\
\hline
Course 1 & 6 & First & English \\
Course 2 & 6 & First & English \\
Course 3 & 12 & Second & German \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\section{Comparison}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{9cm}|p{1cm}|p{5cm}|p{1cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Second Table}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Program A} & \textbf{ECTS} & \textbf{Program B} & \textbf{ECTS} \\
\hline
Course Z & 4 & Course A & 6 \\
Course Y & 5 & Course B & 6 \\
Course X & 5 & Course C & 6 \\
Course W & 2 & & \\
Course V & 2 & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{5mm}
\newline
\begin{tabular}{ |p{9cm}|p{1cm}|p{5cm}|p{1cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Third Table}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Program A} & \textbf{ECTS} & \textbf{Program B} & \textbf{ECTS} \\
\hline
Course \alpha & 4 & Course I & 6 \\
Course \beta & 2 & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You get `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $`  after _any_ error do not even look at the generated PDF, TeX makes no attempt to make sensible output. `\alpha` has to be in math mode.

Comment: for the adding you need to take account of the `\tabcolsep`  padding and the `\arrayrulewidth` width from the vertical lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning the comment by @DavidCarlisle into an answer.

Load the `array` package for a smoother tabular. Then, to align one column of width `5cm` to two columns of width `2.5cm+2.5cm`, you need to take into account two extra `\tabcolsep`s plus one `\arrayrulewidth`. So, instead of `p{5}`, use `p{\dimexpr5cm+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}`.

```
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{1.3}

\section{Course list}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{9cm}|p{1cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{First Table}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Couse} & \textbf{ECTS} &\textbf{Period} & \textbf{Language} \\
\hline
Course 1 & 6 & First & English \\
Course 2 & 6 & First & English \\
Course 3 & 12 & Second & German \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\section{Comparison}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{9cm}|p{1cm}|p{\dimexpr5cm+2\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}|p{1cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Second Table}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Program A} & \textbf{ECTS} & \textbf{Program B} & \textbf{ECTS} \\
\hline
Course Z & 4 & Course A & 6 \\
Course Y & 5 & Course B & 6 \\
Course X & 5 & Course C & 6 \\
Course W & 2 & & \\
Course V & 2 & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{5mm}
\newline
\begin{tabular}{ |p{9cm}|p{1cm}|p{5cm}|p{1cm}|  }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{Third Table}} \\
\hline
\textbf{Program A} & \textbf{ECTS} & \textbf{Program B} & \textbf{ECTS} \\
\hline
Course $\alpha$ & 4 & Course I & 6 \\
Course $\beta$ & 2 & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and also thank you David Carlisle. Can you explain me why and which column isn't 2.5 or 5 cm large?